# Huggingface model inference issue

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface

I'm trying to use my pre-trained huggingface model to predict.

```
    outputs = model(
        ids,
        mask,
        token_type_ids
    )
    outputs = torch.sigmoid(outputs.last_hidden_state).cpu().detach().numpy()
    return outputs[0][0]
```

The I got is

```
[[[0.5144298  0.68467325 0.4045368  ... 0.5698948  0.6843927  0.230076  ]
  [0.526383   0.6108195  0.46920577 ... 0.6635995  0.70778817 0.22947823]
  [0.47112644 0.6557672  0.49308282 ... 0.61219037 0.5811446  0.22059086]
  ...
  [0.46904904 0.66370267 0.4091996  ... 0.5381582  0.70973885 0.2500361 ]
  [0.47025025 0.6625398  0.40454543 ... 0.5423772  0.71071064 0.24768841]
  [0.47398427 0.658539   0.40038437 ... 0.53121835 0.7094869  0.2417065 ]]]
```

What I want is

```
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9998743534088135},
 {'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9996669292449951}]
```

Thanks ahead!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are now performing a sigmoid transformation on all the values of the last hidden state of the bert (i presume?) model. Your softmax is not done over the correct dimension. The code below shows how to do it over the correct dimension (and using batches, which speeds up your code).

You ask for the label with the predicted probabilities (in a binary classification task), which can be gotten by:

```py
    # other code
    logits_ls = [] # the list to store predicted probabilities for the class
    preds_ls = [] # the list to store the predicted classes
    for batch in loader: # assuming you use a dataloader
        logits = outputs.logits
        preds = torch.argmax(logits, dim=1)
        preds_ls.extend(preds.cpu().numpy())
        logits_ls.extend(torch.nn.functional.softmax(logits, dim=-1)[:, 1].cpu().numpy())
    return preds_ls, logits_ls
```

`preds_ls` will contain the labels. The `logits_ls` list will now contain the **probabilities of predicting class 1** for each sample in the loader.

Getting your desired format can be done with simple manipulation of dictionaries in a list. E.g., for the positive predictions when `preds_ls[i]==1`, the `score=logits_ls[i]`. And when `preds_ls[i]==0`, the `score=1-logits_ls[i]`.

EDIT:
You did not mention your exact model, but be sure to use `BertForSequenceClassification` to have access to `outputs.logits`. Any other `...ForSequenceClassification` model from Huggingface can do the same.